How do I create a new column with mean index values for each feature based on geographical distance to all other features using lat/lon coordinates?
I am doing an analysis of how neighbouring organizations influence each other in regards to their innovativeness. I have a dataset containing, among other things, values for an Innovation Index and Lat/Lon data. I need to get the mean value of the Index for all cases within a certain distance, say 50 km.
How do I create a new value for each entry in the dataframe, derived from other entries within a certain geographical distance based on lat/lon?
As a concrete example, my dataset looks like this:
df <- data.frame("Name" = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), 
                 "Index" = c(5,2,8,3,5,9), 
                 "Lat" = c(42.1234, 41.0192, 40.9988, 51.0175, 50.6523, 50.9214), 
                 "Lon" = c(26.5462, 25.9967, 27.0001, 31.1542, 31.8924, 32.1025))

df
>   Name Index     Lat     Lon
> 1    A     5 42.1234 26.5462
> 2    B     2 41.0192 25.9967
> 3    C     8 40.9988 27.0001
> 4    D     3 51.0175 31.1542
> 5    E     5 50.6523 31.8924
> 6    F     9 50.9214 32.1025

What I would like to get to is a dataframe that looks something like this, with the NearbyIndex column displaying the average Index value of the nearby cases:
df2
>   Name Index     Lat     Lon NearbyIndex
> 1    A     5 42.1234 26.5462         5.0
> 2    B     2 41.0192 25.9967         6.5
> 3    C     8 40.9988 27.0001         3.5
> 4    D     3 51.0175 31.1542         7.0
> 5    E     5 50.6523 31.8924         6.0
> 6    F     9 50.9214 32.1025         4.0


Ok, maybe my solution is not the best one in terms of efficiency if your df has lots of rows, but it could be useful as a first attempt.
# Your data
df <- data.frame("Name" = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), 
                 "Index" = c(5,2,8,3,5,9), 
                 "Lat" = c(42.1234, 41.0192, 40.9988, 51.0175, 50.6523, 50.9214), 
                 "Lon" = c(26.5462, 25.9967, 27.0001, 31.1542, 31.8924, 32.1025))

# Setting the distance threshold (I decided to change to 80 km because 50 km was 
# too low for apprecaiting correctly the example)
dist_threshold_km <- 80


# Installing terra package
# install.packages("terra")

# Creating a matrix of distances
# 'lonlat = TRUE' is for applying a Great Circle (WGS84 ellipsoid) distance.
# 'unit = km' do exist but it is not working properly right now, so it'd
# be better to require the values in meters and then divide them by 1e3
distMat <- terra::distance(x = as.matrix(df[,c("Lon", "Lat")]),
                           y = as.matrix(df[,c("Lon", "Lat")]),
                           lonlat = TRUE, unit = "m")/1e3

# 'distMat <= dist_threshold_km' converts your matrix of distance in a boolean
# matrix where the only the values that are less or equal to the threshold will 
# be TRUE. Then every row is used for indexing your df$Index and calculates the 
# mean.
df$NearbyIndex <- apply(X = distMat <= dist_threshold_km, MARGIN = 1, 
                        FUN = \(x, df) mean(df$Index[x]), df = df)

